# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. CSRF cookie not set

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

**ERROR:**

> Reason given for failure: CSRF cookie not set.
>
> In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request
>   Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly.
>   For POST forms, you need to ensure: Your browser is accepting cookies.
>   The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of
>   Context. In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag
>   inside each POST form that targets an internal URL. If you are not
>   using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views
>   that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the
>   POST data. You're seeing the help section of this page because you
>   have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False,
>   and only the initial error message will be displayed. You can
>   customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.

Did everything that I could find, nothing helped, must be something really foolish((

**My template**

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
     {% for field in  form %}
       <div class="control-group">
            {{ field }}
       </div>
     {% endfor %}
     <input type="Submit" id="fsubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" value='Register'/>
</form>
```

**my Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def register_user(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        form = RegisterForm(auto_id=False)
    context['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('templates/register.htm',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Settings**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
```

)

Answer (score 2):

Use csrf_exempt to avoid csrf token.

In view

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

```
@csrf_exempt
def register_user(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        form = RegisterForm(auto_id=False)
    context['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('templates/register.htm',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```